# Oracle merge statment facing deadlock issue

Tags: oracle, sql-merge

I have a simple merge statment given below. But facing deadlock issue sometimes.not sure how to fix it. Is any change required in my code. kindly suggest.

```
MERGE INTO test1 trgt USING (
  SELECT
    serial_ID,
    SYSTEM_STATUS,
    ITEM_STATUS,
    STATUS,
    (
      CASE
        WHEN STATUS IN ('INVALID', 'S001')
        AND ITEM_STATUS IN ('INVALID', 'S001') THEN 'INVALID'
        ELSE coalesce(ITEM_STATUS, STATUS)
      END
    ) change_status
  FROM
    test1
) src ON (trgt.serial_ID = src.serial_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET
  trgt.STATUS = src.change_status,
  trgt.update_date = CASE
    WHEN upper(nvl(trgt.STATUS, '*')) <> upper(nvl(src.change_status, '*')) THEN SYSDATE
    ELSE trgt.update_date
  END,
  trgt.update_user = CASE
    WHEN upper(nvl(trgt.STATUS, '*')) <> upper(nvl(src.change_status, '*')) THEN 'CHANGED_STATUS_UPDATE'
    ELSE trgt.update_user;
```

As this issue not happen frequently so not able to replicate it. Please suggest the fix for the issue.

Comment: Might two processes be executing the same merge simultaneously?

Comment: correct.but how we can fix this issue.any change required in my code. Any hint or any indexing will help?

Comment: Well, the order the rows are assessed is indeterminate, but I don't think adding an `order by` to the `using` clause would fix it. You probably need to manage your processes so only one runs this at a time. If you can't do that externally, you could do a manual lock/unlock of the whole table before/after the merge, but that seems painful. Replacing the merge with a simple update would probably be easier and more effective.

Comment: as sql server has TABLOCKX hint for this kind of issue fix.Do we have any thing similar in oracle sql?I searched for it but not found anything.If i will not get any solution then i will move to simple update statment.Thanks for ur reply and help!

Comment: update statment has also challange to use change_status derived column .It will use to comapre and then set value for update_date and update_user column.

Comment: @user2862073 You should ask your DBA to find the trace file that is generated for every deadlock error. That file will tell you precisely what statements and what objects are causing deadlocks. If you have bitmap indexes or unindexed foreign keys, the cause may not be what you are expecting.